# Remove from HashMap if a key is not in the list

Tags: java, hashmap

Is the any elegant way to remove item from the hash map where the key is not in the given list of items? I would really appreciate if anybody would give a code snippet. If not I would probably do something like this:

```
public HashMap<Integer, NameAndID> getTasksWithWordInFormula(Session session, 
        HashMap<Integer, NameAndID> taskMap, int sectionID, int topicID, int wordID) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Integer> goodList = session.createCriteria(Frbw.class)
            .add(Restrictions.in("id.formulaId", taskMap.keySet()))
            .add(Restrictions.eq("sectionId", sectionID))
            .add(Restrictions.eq("topicId", topicID))
            .add(Restrictions.eq("wordId", wordID))
            .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                 .add(Projections.property("id.formulaId")))
            .setCacheable(true).setCacheRegion("query.DBParadox").list();
    ArrayList<Integer> toRemove = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (Integer formulaID : taskMap.keySet()) 
        if (!goodList.contains(formulaID))
            toRemove.add(formulaID);
    for (Integer formulaID : toRemove) 
        taskMap.remove(formulaID);
    return taskMap;
}
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use [`Set#retainAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#retainAll(java.util.Collection)):

```
taskMap.keySet().retainAll(goodList);
```

---

From [`Map#keySet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet()):

> Returns a `Set` view of the keys contained in this map. **The set is backed by the map, so changes to the map are reflected in the set, and vice-versa.**

(emphasis mine)

Comment: Wow, just what I asked for :)

Comment: Does this work for `values()` instead of `keySet()`?